# Any changes in ngModel field (click, focus) force ngTemplateOutlet re render

Tags: angular6, ngmodel, ng-template

Need some help .... I've had dynamical templates for edit row in table

```
      <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="rowTemplate"
                [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
                  $implicit: rowData,
                  originalData: makeClone(rowData)
                }">
  </ng-container>
makeClone ...json.parse(json.stringlify())
.....
    <ng-template #rowTemplate let-rowData let-originalData>
    <tr>
        <td><input [(ngModel)]="originalData.title"></td>
        <td>
            <button styleClass="ui-button-link" icon="icon-save" (click)="onSave(originalData, rowData)"></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

But when I focused on input and on any changes - my template is re rendering ...and i loose originaldata ...

Show me pls right way to do it

Comment: having this same problem with ngComponentOutlet